# How to get login data (session) outside WordPress?

Tags: login, wp-login-form, session, cookies

I guess WP uses a PHP session (or a cookie) to save login data, right?

I have a website, which uses WP as a CMS, but display (and create) content from outside. I allow anonymous posts, by simply **not** passing `$post['post_author']` to `wp_insert_post()`

However, I also want to make users (that are registered in WP) to be able to login in `mysite/wp/wp-login.php`, than redirect to `mysite/mypage.php`, and get the `user id` from session or cookie.

How do I do that?

### Edit

The code:

```
include( 'wp/wp-load.php');  
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
print_r($current_user);
```

this prints an empty WP_User Object:

```
WP_User Object ( [data] => [ID] => 0 [caps] => Array ( ) [cap_key] => [roles] => Array ( ) [allcaps] => Array ( ) [filter] => )
```

Although I'm logged in in WP.

*P.S.*
Now that I saw `wp-login-form` in tags, which gave me a better idea.

Can I put a login form to my page (outside wp) ? This would surely be better, since it wouldn't require the users to redirect.

I want minimum (ideally zero) interaction between `mysite/wp` and visitors (including Google Bot).

Comment: Something like this?  http://wpengineer.com/1038/embed-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress/

Comment: @PatJ yes, but I'm already doing that. However, I couldn't manage to get the login data.

Comment: It will help us help you if you post the code you *are* using to try to get the login data.

Comment: I pasted the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem, and it could definitely help others too.

The problem was with cookies since my folder structure was like this :

- mysite.com
- mysite.com/mypage.php

  - mysite/wordpress/

the cookies were only valid for wordpress folder, and it's subdirectories.

In order to activate the cookies outside wordpress, I installed the [root Cookie](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/root-cookie) plugin, and everything works fine now.

### P.S.

Do **NOT** change the configuration of root Cookie. Just leave the Domain Name setting as empty.

Comment: You can do it without a plugin. In Your wp-config.php add before `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');` `define('SITECOOKIEPATH','/');define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH','/');` to set the cookie in all domain